# Why are my element id returning Null?

Tags: javascript, html, null

code snippet: HTML

```
               <div id="imgpreview" name="imgpreview">
                   <img id="srcimg" name="srcimg" />

                   <div id="resident_name"></div>
                   <div id="resident_addr"></div>
                   <div id="resident_contact"></div>
                   <div id="sale_or_rent">
                       <img id="for_sale_img" class="obtn" src="../images/ads/ForSaleSignSm.jpg" />
                       <img id="for_rent_img" class="obtn" src="../images/ads/ForRentSignSm.gif" />
                   </div>
               </div>
```

code snippet: Javascript

```
function div_obj( id )
{
    if( document.layers ) return document.layers[id];

    else if( document.all ) return document.all[id];

    else if( document.getElementById ) return document.getElementById( id );

    else return null;
}
```

Returns the ID for the "imgpreview" DIV, but all others, IMG and DIV return null.  It occurs regardless if I have a SRC defined, or not, for the "srcimg" IMG.  Anybody have a clue why this occurs?   I've been staring at this for so long, I am sure a new set of eyes will help.  TIA.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome because it is compatible with most browsers and IE 8 because it is not.

Answer (score 5):

That code has to be like 10 years old -- simply scrap everything except `return document.getElementById(id);`. I don't see why that would not work under any circumstances.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus, I shall, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Because "srcimg" and the rest aren't in the top level of the document?  Why not just use document.getElementById()?

Edit:  Oh!  those other elements aren't in the document because you tried to close your first image with a backslash instead of a forward slash.  The backslash is basically ignored which means that the image definition just goes on and on and on.

Change the second line to:

```
 <img id="srcimg" name="srcimg" />
```

instead of

```
 <img id="srcimg" name="srcimg" \>
```

Comment: I am digging into books, some obviously old, the internet and anywhere I can learn from.  Common answer appears to be use document.getElementById().  I have taken the advice, tried it, same results.  What is this top level you mention and why is that important?

Comment: <body>
    <div id="desktop">
        <div id="leftctx">
            <div id="body">
                <div id="centercol">
                   <div id="imgpreview" name="imgpreview">

Comment: Wait.  So just calling document.getElementById("resident_name") doesn't work, for instance?

Comment: Right.  If the "resident_name" DIV is on the same level or above the "imgpreview" DIV, the getElementById works, just not as a child, nor anything else that is a child, of "imgpreview".  This is weird because, as you see from the simple tree, above, even the "imgpreview" DIV is a child of a child of a child..  This is why I am beside myself with puzzlement.

Comment: I caught the typo also but, thanks for the observation; however, for me, the results are the same, NULL is still returned for any getElementByID  inside the "imgpreview" DIV.

Comment: At this point, I would use a debugger to look at the structure of the rendered HTML.  I use "Web Developer" in Chrome, and "Firebug" in Firefox.

I would also fix the typo in your original post, to prevent others from thinking that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to worry about document.all and document.layers.  `document.getElementById(id)` is cross-browser compatible back to IE4

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will adjust my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa.

The issue turned out to be a hide_img function in the onload that set the innerHTML for the "imgpreview" DIV to "" thereby, erasing all of the elements in the "imgpreview" DIV.

I truly appreciate the code suggestions because they led me to better style and to evaluate each referencing function revealing the culprit.

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("imgpreview").children[0].src = "images/new_dis.png";
```

it change `"srcimg"` elemet src

Comment: a little bit of explanation would be nice

Comment: if we want to reach object by  document.getElementById("srcimg") it will return null. But img tag that have  id="srcimg"  is a child of parent div that have id="imgpreview" so, in child of parent div we can reach img element atribute. document.getElementById("imgpreview").children[0].src is src artibute of our first img tag that have id="srcimg"